# How to use the special character < for assigning shortcut-keys in openbox config file?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xml, lubuntu, openbox, lxde

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/ five characters need to be escaped in XML documents under some circumstances:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

I tried to use `Winkey <` as a shortcut-key for some command in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. I did the following attempts, both failed:

```
<keybind key="W-<">
 <action name="Execute">
<command>lxterminal</command>
</action>
</keybind>


<keybind key="W-&lt;">
 <action name="Execute">
<command>lxterminal</command>
</action>
</keybind>
```

How can I use `Winkey <` as a shortcut-key for some command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the [help](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Keys) for bindings, you can use the *name* of the key, in this case "less", found from using `xev`, so try `key="W-less"`.